# User assigned IAM Admin role cannot see VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-iam

In AWS, I created a user and gave this user AdministratorAcess permissions.

The way I understand it, this user can do everything the root administrator can: clicking on the AdministratorAccess permission, gives me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I sign into the console, with this user's credentials, I cannot see any of the VPCs or subnets or the internet gateway, previously created by the root user.

Did I misunderstand how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. You are not in the **correct Region** - make sure that you are where you want to be in the top-right corner (e.g. *Ohio*, *N. Virginia*, etc.)
2. You may be in a **wrong AWS account** (if you have many accounts to works with).
3. You may be restricted by **[IAM Permissions Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)** that limit the actual effective permissions you can have, even if your IAM policy allows more.

I bet it's the region though...

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, it's the region. I did not think of that.